# Set minimum input quantity even on ajax add to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I have added the below code on my function.php (minimum as 6 qty for every product) it is reflect on my product category page…

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min','woocommerce_quantity_input_min_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_quantity_input_min_callback( $min, $product ) {
    $min = 6;  
    return $min;
}
```

But while clicking the add to cart button (Ajax) the cart page only have 1 qty not 6 qty… How to fix this?

Need qty 6 on cart page for each product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need also to set the quantity on add to cart event *(+ Ajax)* and to set the input value + the minimum input value quantity at the same time. So try the following instead:

```
// Set product quantity added to cart (handling ajax add to cart)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_quantity','woocommerce_add_to_cart_quantity_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_add_to_cart_quantity_callback( $quantity, $product_id ) {
    if( $quantity < 6 ) {
        $quantity = 6;
    }
    return $quantity;
}

// Set the product quantity min value
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_quantity_input_args_callback( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value'] = 6;
    $args['min_value']   = 6;

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much LoicTheAztec. It is working perfectly.