# Woocommerce Ajax cart update change min qty from 0 to 1

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Here is a part of the code of the plugin that I found, I think that give the functionnality of the plugin.

```
// Only if WooCommerce is active (doesn't work for Github installations which have version number in folder name).
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) || ( get_site_option('active_sitewide_plugins') && array_key_exists( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', get_site_option('active_sitewide_plugins') ) ) ) {
    
    // Remove plugin prefix and dash "_" from argument keys.
    function acau_replaceArrayKeys( $array ) {
        $replacedKeys = str_replace('acau_', null, array_keys( $array ));
        return array_combine( $replacedKeys, $array );
    }
    $args = acau_replaceArrayKeys ( $acau_settings_page->acau_get_settings() );
    
    // Run plugin.
    add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ); });
    function ajax_cart_autoupdate( $args ) {
        
        if (! is_cart() ) return; // Only if it's a cart page.
        
        // Enqueue js script inline using wc_enqueue_js.
        add_action( 'template_redirect', function() use ( $args ) { acau_enqueue_script ( $args ); }, 20);
        
        /*don't display default "Update cart" button, its behavior can still be triggered automatically,
        in WooCommerce 3.4.0 input element type was changed to button,
        class .button is present in all versions (at least from 2.6 when AJAX cart appeared in WooCommerce core) 
        change spinning wheel color*/
        add_action( 'wp_head', function() use ( $args ) { acau_apply_styles ( $args ); }, 20);
        
        // Cart page minimum qty = 1 instead of 0.
        if (1 == $args['positive_qty'] ) {              
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'acau_cart_min_qty', 10, 2 );                
        }
        
        /* Don't display any notices, it includes:
        - "Cart updated."
        - removed cart item notice
        - the one when checkout session expires and cart items disappear (it duplicates no items in cart standard message).
        */      
        if (1 == $args['cart_notices_off'] ) {
            WC()->session->set( 'wc_notices', null );
        }
        
    }
    
    function acau_apply_styles( $args ) {
        $my_style = "
        [name='update_cart'] {
            display: none!important;
        }" .        
        (( 1 == $args['custom_spinning_wheel'] ) ?
        ".woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,.woocommerce .loader:before {    
            color: " . $args['spinning_wheel_color'] . ";
        }" : "");
        
        echo '<style>' . acau_minify($my_style) . '</style>';
    }
    
    function acau_enqueue_script( $args ) {
        
        wc_enqueue_js( '
        
            var timeout;

            jQuery("div.woocommerce").on("change keyup mouseup", "input.qty, select.qty", function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
                if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
                if (jQuery(this).val() == "") return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery("[name=\"update_cart\"]").trigger("click");
                }, ' . $args["update_delay"] . ' ); // schedule update cart event with delay in miliseconds specified in plugin settings
            });
            
        ' );
        
    }
        
    function acau_cart_min_qty( $args, $product ) {
        $args['min_value'] = 1;
        return $args;
    }
}

function acau_minify( $input ) { 
    $output = $input;
    // Remove whitespace
    $output = preg_replace('/\s*([{}|:;,])\s+/', '$1', $output);
    // Remove trailing whitespace at the start
    $output = preg_replace('/\s\s+(.*)/', '$1', $output);
    // Remove comments
    // $output = preg_replace('#/\*.*?\*/#s', '', $output);
    $output = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:(?<!\:|\\\|\')\/\/.*))/', '', $output);
    return $output;
}
```

Here is the parts of the code that I kept to only maintain the functions that I need: AJAX cart auto update, not allow qty to drop below 1 and remove the cart update button. I does half work. It refresh the cart like it should but I can still drop the qty below 1.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'auto_update_cart_totals' );
function auto_update_cart_totals( ) {    
    if (! is_cart( ) ) return; // Only if it's cart page.
    // Enqueue js file.
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_cart_autoupdate' ); 
    if ( ['positive_qty'] ) {               
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'acau_cart_min_qty', 10, 2 );
}

function my_cart_autoupdate( ) {
   add_action('wp_head', 'hide_update_cart_button', 20);

    function hide_update_cart_button( ) {
    echo "<style>.button[name='update_cart']{ display: none!important;}</style>";
}
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-cart-autoupdate', 'path-to-js-file-its-name-and-extension', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
    
function acau_cart_min_qty ( ) {
    ['min_value'] = 1; return;
}
}
```

Here is the Jquery code that I've added to a Oxygen code block.

```
var timeout;

jQuery("div.woocommerce").on("change keyup mouseup", "input.qty, select.qty", function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
  if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
  if (jQuery(this).val() == "") return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("[name=\"update_cart\"]").trigger("click");
  },1000 ); // schedule update cart event with delay in miliseconds specified in plugin settings
});
```

Comment: I don't really know what do you mean but what I can tell is that on the cart page I do have a qty field that have plus and minus buttons because of added plugin. I forgot to mention that all the codes above are from a plugin, I try only to keep the codes and make it work without the plugin. By default the plugin have a functionality to not allow qty to drop below 1.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495958/3825777

Comment: I had a look to your link but doesn't work for my use. Or I haven't been able to get it working.
I've posted a part of the code of the plugin, the part that I think give it's functionnality, there is lot more code but seems only for customisation from wordpress admin panel.
The second code is the "cleaned" code that I wrote but doesn't work for the qty even if I've added the condition. Maybe a problem with brackets?

Comment: Back up a few steps and try a different approach and post a new question.  The timeout code looks especially bad.  Why is having a quantity of 0 such a bad thing anyway?  I hate shopping carts that make it difficult to remove items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Purpose is mostly for learning. But I'm far to have the knoweldge to have it work! Basicully having 0 as qty to remove item is useless as there is already a button to remove item. It's mostly to avoid the item to be accidentally removed.